# Extracting integers (of varying length) before specific string in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract integers of varying length from a data frame column ($description) that precedes a known string. For example, I wish to extract the integers that appear before the string "yard" in the following (each line represents a separate entry in the dataframe column):

(3:18) B.Green-Ellis left end to NE 28 for -1 yards (A.Ross).

(1:07) (No Huddle Shotgun) B.Green-Ellis right guard to NYG 27 for 4 yards (C.Blackburn).

(14:00) B.Green-Ellis right end pushed ob at NYG 33 for 17 yards (K.Phillips).

What makes it problematic is that the integer can vary in length (i.e. 4 or 17), but it can also be negative.

I really have tried everything I can think of, and have been searching all day for a related thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be

```
s1 <- "(3:18) B.Green-Ellis left end to NE 28 for -1 yards (A.Ross)."
ss1 <- strsplit(s1, split = " ")[[1]]
as.numeric(ss1[grep("yards", ss1) -1])
```

now you just have to put this in a loop and apply to every row, i.e

```
s1 <- "(3:18) B.Green-Ellis left end to NE 28 for -1 yards (A.Ross)."
s2 <- "(1:07) (No Huddle Shotgun) B.Green-Ellis right guard to NYG 27 for 4 yards  (C.Blackburn)."
s3 <- "(14:00) B.Green-Ellis right end pushed ob at NYG 33 for 17 yards (K.Phillips)."

df <- rbind(s1,s2,s3)

splits <- strsplit(df[, 1], split = " ")
sapply(splits, function(z) z[grep("yards", z) - 1])
```

you can also do this in one step, as @joshua suggested!

Comment: No need to put it in a loop, `strsplit` is already vectorized: `sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(s) s[grep(s, pattern="yards")-1])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use some straightforward regex with `gsub` and work *from the end* of your strings:

```
temp <- c("(3:18) B.Green-Ellis left end to NE 28 for -1 yards (A.Ross).", 
          "(1:07) (No Huddle Shotgun) B.Green-Ellis right guard to NYG 27 for 4 yards (C.Blackburn).", 
          "(14:00) B.Green-Ellis right end pushed ob at NYG 33 for 17 yards (K.Phillips).")
as.numeric(gsub("^(.*)( [-1-9]+)(.*)$", "\\2", temp))
# [1] -1  4 17
```

Looking at the regex:

- `^.*` -- matches anything... up to the point that...
- ... it runs into a space followed by any number of digits `[-0-9]+`, some possibly with a `-` before them, and which are followed by...
- ... anything `.*$`, to the end of the input.

The brackets are used for "backreferencing". You'll notice there are three groups in the above example, and we're only interested in the results from the second group, hence the `\\2` as our replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly complicated... but works for me assuming a space before the number... I couldn't get a regex to extract the number itself...

```
# the data...
yards <- c("(3:18) B.Green-Ellis left end to NE 28 for -1 yards (A.Ross).", 
"(1:07) (No Huddle Shotgun) B.Green-Ellis right guard to NYG 27 for 4 yards (C.Blackburn).", 
"(14:00) B.Green-Ellis right end pushed ob at NYG 33 for 17 yards (K.Phillips).")

# handy function from http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/reverse-string-td2288532.html
strReverse <- function(x) sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")
# remove everything after ' yard'
y1 <- gsub(' *yard.*$', '', yard)
# reverse and remove everything after the space and reverse again
as.numeric(strReverse(gsub(' .*$','', strReverse(y1))))
```

Comment: @JimGrange - you can "up vote" things you like when you get enough points!